# positioning three divs with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

```
<body>
 <div id="red" class="colorbox"><p>RED</p>
  <div id="green" class="colorbox"><p>GREEN </p>
   <div id="blue" class="colorbox"><p>BLUE</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

How can I positioning it like this:

red block is placed between the other two in the Z axis;
green block is placed behind the red block;
blue block is placed in front of the red block.

something like this:

```css
#red { z-index: 2; }
#green { z-index: 1 }
#blue { z-index: 3 }
```

Advance inordinately thanks!

UPDATED:

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/ihizot/3/edit

Comment: Add position:relative; to each, then the z-index values will work.

Comment: not as simple as that @mookamafoob - see my answer

Comment: @PaulSullivan Lol that's why it was a comment, not an answer. It was a starting point :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply you can't do this and be 100% cross browser supported (see the answer by `mookamafoob` that uses psuedo element :after to recreate the red box (not supported < IE8)).

Because the red and blue divs are contained in the green you cannot push the stacking context of the red above it.

I have created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcnR/) with what would be the z-index and css needed in order to stack these  as you require BUT because your markup is nested 'incorrectly' the red is not able to push between the green and blue divs.

```
#red {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:15px;
  left:15px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red
}
#green
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:1;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:green;
}
#blue
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Not possible as far as I know and I'm sure someone will use the correct terminology for why this happens in the browser rendering engines (anyone?)

Comment: I will try find the exact reason @dimiork but (from my experience) I just know this is the way the rendering engines in css work. I believe if you research 'css stacking context' in google you'll probably be able to gleen more information on the subject. And no problem always happy to help :)

Comment: Don't give up so easily! See my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

For z-index to work you need to set a position on each of those elements:

position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed

Example:

```
<div id="green" class="colorbox"><p>RED</p>
  <div id="red" class="colorbox"><p>GREEN </p>
   <div id="blue" class="colorbox"><p>BLUE</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

.colorbox {
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;

}
#red { 
  background:red;
  z-index: 2; 
}
#green { 
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
}
#blue { 
  z-index: 3;
  background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Yup it is not as simple as the answer states. Because of the markup structure you cannot break the red div above the green div (see my answer and fiddle for example

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it actually **is** possible, using CSS pseudo elements and it will work in most browsers. If you recreate the "red" box with the following:

```
#red:after {
background-color: #f00;
top: -5px;
left: -5px;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
font-weight: bold;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 5px solid white;
font-size: 70pt;
content:"RED";
```

}

and make a couple other tweaks, you will get [this](http://jsbin.com/avohis/1/edit) example where it sits between the other two. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works for the scenario you provided.

Comment: Apart from <IE8 not supporting :after this is a very nice solution... I give you +1 but have a feeling the OP might not as it's not 100% cross browser supported :(

Comment: @PaulSullivan It's true, but once you've gotten into anything interesting with z-index, you're basically throwing IE7 out the window :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with Z-index is it not possible to change the markup?

```
<div id="green" class="colorbox"><p>GREEN </p>
    <div id="red" class="colorbox"><p>RED</p>  
      <div id="blue" class="colorbox"><p>BLUE</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the question - I am sure he could easily switch the ID's of the tags BUT the OP asked if it were possible to layout as he requested  using the structure as defined in the question (which I believe it is not possible due to the stacking context)

Comment: question is of academic interest in this form, which is at the moment
Guys, you saved my night's sleep today :)